# What function produces the pictured graph?

Tags: functions

Quite simply, I need a function that will produce a graph similar to the one below. Important to note:

1) Y switches from negative to positive at X=1/3

2) Y ranges from -0.1 to +0.1, not to and from infinity

3) Y should be very close to 0 by X=1/6 and X=3/6.

4) It should have curves similar to those in the picture *(Mod note: the original image link is dead, for context I'm replacing it with the graph of the function given in the accepted answer.)*

[image]

A massive thank-you to whomever can figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest

$$\frac1{5\pi}\mathrm{arccot}\left(c\left(x-\frac13\right)\right)$$

and adjust the value of $c$ to speed up or slow the rate of decrease.

---

Yet another alternative:

$$\frac1{10}\tanh\left(\frac1{c\left(x-\frac13\right)}\right)$$

Comment: This looks to be exactly correct (according to WolframAlpha's grapher), however, it seems Lua doesn't have an arccotangent function...

Comment: @Taehl: $\mathrm{arccot}(x)=\arctan(1/x)$

Comment: I must be expressing this wrong... (1/(5*pi))*atan(1/(x-1/3)) seems incorrect...

Comment: [Looks good to me.](http://fooplot.com/index.php?&y0=atan%281/%28100%28x-1/3%29%29%29/%285*pi%29&ixmin=-5&ixmax=5&iymin=-3&iymax=3&igx=0.1&igy=0.01&igl=1&igs=0&iax=1&ila=1&xmin=-0.25&xmax=0.8&ymin=-0.1&ymax=0.1)

Comment: The tanh one worked even better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need continuity when you go through $x=\frac{1}{3}$?  If not, you can use
$y=0.1 \exp(-a(x-1/3))$ for $x \gt \frac{1}{3}$

$y=-0.1 \exp(a(x-1/3))$ for $x \lt \frac{1}{3}$

Pick $a$  to make it fall as fast as you want

Comment: That was very close, and led me to a useable function - thank you! What I ended up with was: (n<1/3 and -.1^(-(n-1/3)) or .1^(n-1/3))/10)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $H$, the following seems to be the simplest choice

$y=H(x-\frac13)(1-H(x-\frac12))(x-\frac12)^2-(1-H(x-\frac13))H(x-\frac16)(x-\frac16)^2$